# Explode function in PHP

Tags: php

I have the following notepad file;

```
dbName:              

tableName:       

numberOfFields:
```

I am trying to write a php app which assigns the value of dbName to $dbName, tableName to $tableName and numberOfFields to $numFields.

My code is:

```
$handle = @fopen("config.txt", "r");
if ($handle) {
    while (!feof($handle)) {
        $buffer = fgets($handle, 4096);
        list($dbName, $tableName, $numFields) = explode(":", "$buffer");
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```

however, ":" doesn't work as there are line breaks in between dbName and table Name. How do I explode $buffer, keeping the line breaks in the notepad file?

Thank you.

Comment: I'd suggest a couple of things also - not using '@' to suppress warnings or errors, and also, using file_get_contents or file() rather than fopen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at the `file` function. It takes care of opening and reading the file, and returns an array of lines from the file.  You could then iterate through the array and operate on each line individually.

http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.file.php

Comment: $lines = file('/path/to/file.txt');
$line3 = $lines[2];

Comment: might wanna mention that there will be a \n or \r or \r\n (new line char[s]) on the end of that.  so you'd wanna do `rtrim( $lines[ 2 ] )` if it's something critical like a user/pass (not markup).

Comment: is there a way I can select odd numbered lines and even numbered lines?

Comment: Sure, just call fgets twice inside the loop. First call gets line 1, second call gets line 2. Next loop iteration, first call gets line 3, second call gets line 4, etc.

Comment: (note that with `file` you don't need to use fgets at all...).   You could use a for-loop to iterate through the array, flipping a boolean variable on each iteration.  That would give you odd/even/odd/even/odd...

Comment: after using explode, is each element a string?

Answer (score 1):

you can do this:

```
$data=file_get_contents("file");
$s  = preg_split("/\n\n+/m", $data);
print_r($s);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the chr($INT); function to look for the line break in your explode call.

Your can find more on the chr function here:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.chr.php

Add you can find the ascii chars for line break at:

http://www.asciitable.com/

Answer (score 0):

`fgets` returns only one line. There is no way `$buffer` would ever have all three items at once, so that assignment to `list()` is wrong. For the first line, `explode()` will return an array with two items: `"dbName"` (text before the colon) and `""` (text after the colon).

Answer (score 0):

Does this work:

```
list ($dbName, $tableName, $numFields) = explode (':', implode ('', file ('config.txt')));
```

Comment: no, it returns

"dbName tableName numberOfFields " when i echo $dbName

Answer (score 0):

If you're sure of the line contents, and the file will not grow arbitrarily large:

```
  1 <?php
  2 
  3 $handle = @fopen("config.txt", "r");
  4 if ($handle) {
  5     $buffer = "";
  6     while (!feof($handle)) {
  7         $buffer = $buffer . trim(fgets($handle, 4096));
  8     }
  9     fclose($handle);
 10 
 11     list($dbName, $tableName, $numFields) = explode(":", $buffer);
 12 }
 13 
 14 ?>
```

The while loop will go through all the lines and concatenate onto the same buffer after removing whitespace.  This leaves just the content separated by ":".  This is now amenable to explode.

As Nicolas wrote, feof gets one line at a time, so the list assignment needs to happen outside the loop.